# Is it safe to keep calling View.invalidate so that onDraw is called constantly?

Tags: java, android

So I have this Canvas View which draws stuff from `Canvas` class, the thing is that `onDraw` in my Canvas view class is only called on certain time like moving from app to another app or anything that affects the screen and the layout. So I found that `View.invalidate` will call `onDraw` so that i will repaint all of the layout. So I made it like this to make my `onDraw` is called constantly, but is it safe? I mean I do feel some FPS drops in a certain time, is there a better way to make sure onDraw is called constantly?

```java
private class CanvasView extends View{
    public CanvasView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        native_onDraw(canvas, width, height, density);

        this.invalidate(); // refresh everything
    }
}
```

Comment: i think constant reDraw would consume unwanted resources (battery/CPU/memory). You should consider identifying points when redraw should happen and the force invalidate() only at that point(s).

Comment: @BirenderSingh yes I have thinked about it. The thing is that I need onDraw to be "really" called constantly since my native use draw functions real time. calling like every 1-2 seconds will make my gui hang for that time.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding OnDraw() and calling invalidate is a good way to achieve a display that updates every frame, and this will be resource consuming. On the other hand you can check out the [Choreographer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html) class.